# Can't install python packages/modules inside a virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I don't know what just happened or what I did. It suddenly just can't install the python packages/modules when I tried to install them.

I am using a macbook pro laptop. I have been using virtual environment, there were no problems until now. I tried these in my terminal while I'm on the virtual environment:

```
pip install pandas
pip install mezzanine
pip install django
```

and I always received this message.
[image]

> 

I tried to uninstall virtualenv, pip, and used pip3, but nothing works. On the other hand, I tried installing those packages/modules without using the virtual environment, and everything went well.

I have two python versions, the python3 and python2.

> Does it matter to know which python version is pip using? (I THINK YES?!)

I CREATED A VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT USING PIP, IT CREATED A VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT WITH PYTHON 2 VERSION INSTALLED, BUT WHEN ASKED TYPE THIS IN THE TERMINAL:

```
pip --version
```

WHAT CAME OUT WAS THAT IT'S ON PYTHON 3.6

```
pip 10.0.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

FOR MORE INFO:

ll --> name of virtual environment: python 2 version used

Python2:

```
/Users/macintosh/Documents/ll/bin/python2
```

Python 3:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

This did not happened before. I can use "pip install [module name]" without any problem like this before. I don't know what happened. So, I can't fix it. My last resort is to format everything in my laptop which is sad. Please help thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Can you please explain it sir? I do not understand. Sorry I am not well knowledgeable about this. Thank you sir

Comment: Your `pip` has lost the ability to verify SSL certificates. Common causes include an update of OS X where python doesn't know where the cacert bundle is located anymore or you are connecting through a corporate proxy/firewall that uses its own certificate so it can decrypt all the traffic. You can bypass the SSL checking by adding  `--trusted-host` flag to pip. This leaves you vulnerable to malware injection though, so best to fix your SSL issues.

Answer (score 2):

from [official](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

> if you are working in a Virtual Environment created by virtualenv or
>   pyvenv. Just make sure to upgrade pip.

upgrade pip by

On Linux or macOS:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late but in my case I had to create a new virtualenv with:

```
python -m virtualenv <virtual_env_venv>
```

then (after activating it) I was able to do a successful installation in the new virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Use a terminal and write this code:

```
python -m install [module name]
```

Use this code without keys and replace the module name ,your preference module.

Comment: I think you mean "python -m pip install [module name]?" I tried it before (also now), it does not work :'(

Comment: Hey Man,i think that This is do not work because your python version is old

Comment: I already upgraded my python just before I posted this post, sir, and still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This line worked for installing in my python virtual environment:

```
python -m pip install [module name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using windows command prompt, it was showing the same error. Then I tried installing libraries in the virtual environment using anaconda prompt. It was working